# Collapse UITableViewCells while dragging

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have the following structure in a UITableView:

```
Recipe 1:
--> Ingredient a
--> Ingredient b
--> Ingredient c
Recipe 2:
--> Ingredient d
--> Ingredient e
```

Recipes and ingredients are both UITableViewCells and you can press on a button that is displayed in the Recipe cell to collapse or expand the Recipe and hide or show its ingredients.

When I'm in edit mode, I want to be able to reorder Recipes using the native drag feature available in UITableView. When a user start dragging a Recipe, if it is expanded, I need it to be collapsed. However, I can't detect when dragging starts (to collapse the Recipe).

I've tried using a UILongPressGestureRecognizer with a minimumPressDuration = 0 and if the touch event ocurrs in the zone where cell's reorder accessory view is displayed I collapse de Recipe. However, when I detect the tap, if I change the datasource and reload the UITableView to collapse the Receipe the dragging is interrupted.

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have recently implemented something very similar.  I started down the tableView path, but opted for using a series of UIButtons.  This gives you control over the collapsing/expanding and also the dragging can reorder the buttons as you drag the recipe down your list.  Animation effects were very straightforward.  As far as deleting - you could mimic the table view method so that the UI is consistent with users expectations.

Comment: Collapsing recipes when dragging starts is the only problem I'm having with the native UITableView. I don't think it worths creating a new component from the scratch. I hope so...

Comment: @TomSwift nop, I'm just moving the parent element and when it's dropped I move children.